# MVC 5: dictionary in model bound to a series of checkboxes in view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dictionary, model-binding

When I POST my model to the controller to save it, the controller gets an empty dictionary.

Where do things go wrong? Is there something special to do for binding to work?

My model has this property:

`public Dictionary<int, bool> DictionaryTest { get; set; }`

My controller fills some data before calling the view:

`mymodel.DictionaryTest = new Dictionary<int, bool> { { 0, false }, { 1, true }, { 2, false } };`

My view correctly displays it with this code:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m_ => m_.DictionaryTest[0], new { @class = "form-control" })
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m_ => m_.DictionaryTest[1], new { @class = "form-control" })
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m_ => m_.DictionaryTest[2], new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39937281/mvc-post-controller-method-get-empty-dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to bind a dictionary, you need to have post values like: `DictionaryProperty[N].Key` and `DictionaryProperty[N].Value`. As a result, your Razor code would need to look something like:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m_ => m_.DictionaryTest[0].Key)
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m_ => m_.DictionaryTest[0].Value, new { @class = "form-control" })

@Html.HiddenFor(m_ => m_.DictionaryTest[1].Key)
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m_ => m_.DictionaryTest[1].Value, new { @class = "form-control" })

@Html.HiddenFor(m_ => m_.DictionaryTest[2].Key)
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m_ => m_.DictionaryTest[2].Value, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

However, if your keys are integers, a dictionary is overkill. Just use a simple list. Then, your Razor code would work as-is.

Comment: A simple list was great in this case. Thanks a lot.

Comment: The class you append to the checkboxes should be `form-check-input` if you're using bootstrap.

Answer (score 1):

I thought I'd write something up here, because I tried the accepted answer and ended up with compilation issues - and I don't know about you guys, but the line `DictionaryTest[index].Key` just doesn't work for me - since when did array-accessing require a `Key` property?!

To anyone else hunting for an answer on this, there are a few tricks to it that will make this all work like magic. In a nutshell, it all hinges on this:

In order for multiple properties to bind together into one object (be that a list of any complex type, or a dictionary), the model binder needs to know **which properties belong grouped together** - otherwise it gets tangled up.

Let's say you have a type like so:

```
public class TestClass
{
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
}
```

And you want it to bind into a method like this:

```
public ActionResult MyAction(List<TestClass> test)
{
    ...
}
```

If you just dump a bunch of inputs on the page like this:

```
<input name="Prop1" value="FirstP1" />
<input name="Prop2" value="FirstP2" />

<input name="Prop1" value="SecondP1" />
<input name="Prop2" value="SecondP2" />
```

How does the model binder know which ones go together? Short answer: **it doesn't** - it needs a little help. As you probably already know, the key is to give it related indices so it can figure out which ones to group:

```
<input name="test[0].Prop1" value="FirstP1" />
<input name="test[0].Prop2" value="FirstP2" />

<input name="test[1].Prop1" value="SecondP1" />
<input name="test[1].Prop2" value="SecondP2" />
```

Now the model binder can group the first two `[0]` together and the next two `[1]` together, and voila we have a list bound.

**Note:** veterans out there will recall, that it's important your indices stay in order - if they end up incomplete or out of order (e.g. you end up with `[0]`,`[3]`, `[1]` due to some client-side delete or sort) then you'll face troubles, as the model binder goes looking sequentially. You can solve this by adding some client-side JS to reassign the names sequentially on form-save - and that works a treat. Or you can read on:

#### What about dictionaries?

Once you understand the above, getting dictionaries to bind is actually pretty simple: given that they are really just a `List<KeyValuePair<X,Y>>`:

```
<input name="test[0].Key" value="Item1" />
<input name="test[0].Value" value="Item1Value" />

<input name="test[1].Key" value="Item2" />
<input name="test[1].Value" value="Item2Value" />
```

However, the same issues/limitations apply if you're submitting indices that are out-of-order. One specific scenario here are **checkboxes** - if you have a `Dictionary<string, bool>` (or any other key type) that you want to bind as checkboxes, you'll recall that HTML doesn't submit unchecked checkboxes in form submissions. So if you only tick a few items, you end up with a partial list where the indices are guaranteed to be out of order.

Solution 1: do the JS thing client-side to rewrite the indices before form submit, to force them to be sequential. Totally doable, but annoying.

Solution 2: use out-of-order keys, by helping the model binder understand which ones to look for. It's pretty simple: you just need one extra input, to define the index:

```
<input type="hidden" name="test.Index" value="IndexA" />
<input name="test[IndexA].Key" value="IndexAKey" />
<input name="test[IndexA].Value" value="IndexAValue" />

<input type="hidden" name="test.Index" value="SomeOtherIndex" />
<input name="test[SomeOtherIndex].Key" value="SomeOtherIndexKey" />
<input name="test[SomeOtherIndex].Value" value="SomeOtherIndexValue" />
```

That extra input with the name `<collectionName>.Index` gives the model binder just the nudge it needed to sort it all out. For a dictionary, it's handy to use the dictionary key as the custom index, just so everything lines up - it feels a bit redundant, but it does work:

```
<input type="hidden" name="test.Index" value="IndexAKey" />
<input name="test[IndexAKey].Key" value="IndexAKey" />       //<-- totally feel like this line doesn't need to be there, but it works
<input name="test[IndexAKey].Value" value="IndexAValue" />
```

To come full-circle, the notation of `Dictionary[index].Key` is totally what needs to happen - but that should be a `string`, and in a HTML input `name` property - not in a `Html.HiddenFor()` helper.

Peace out folks!

Comment: Have you tried using the `ElementAt()` method of Dictionary ? Instead of `DictionaryTest[index].Key` you would have `DictionaryTest.ElementAt(index).Key` Where index is an integer. This may help you in case your key is not an integer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working ASP.NET MVC 5 example that overcomes any `[*]` trouble by calling the simple, yet not intuitive, `ToArray()` method before accessing elements. This allows you to access dictionary elements with the array accessor (and thus, indices) regardless of your dictionary's Key type.

I've placed this `.cshtml` file inside my `Shared/EditorTemplates` folder so I can now use it with any Dictionary<string, bool> by invoking `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.MyDictionary)`.

**Note** : do not try using `foreach` loop. ASP.NET MVC's model binder really needs indices as explained in other solutions.

**Fun note** : you could actually write a foreach loop like `foreach(int i in Enumerable.Range(0, Model.Count))`

```
@model Dictionary<string, bool>

@* 
  BOOTSTRAP V5 only support row-cols-* until * == 6, 
  extend the class if you need to display more items in a row 
*@

<div class="form-group row row-cols-@Model.Count">
  @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
  {
    <div class="col form-check">
      <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(model => Model.ToArray()[i].Value, Model.ToArray()[i].Key, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-check-label" })

        @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.ToArray()[i].Key)
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => Model.ToArray()[i].Value, new { @class = "form-check-input" })
      </div>
    </div>
  }
</div>
```

**EDIT** : the index trick is now mentioned in the [official Blazor documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-6.0#navlink-and-navmenu-components) (ASP's little brother) as a **'Warning'**. (at the end of the linked document)